# Kак изменить цвет половины текста в Text View

Tags: android, textview, текст, android-textview

Как сделать такой разноцветный текст.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Для этого нужно использовать [Spannable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable), а именно -- ForegroundColorSpan.

0 -- индекс начала применения цвета в строке, 5 -- индекс конца

```
    val text = SpannableString("Твой текст").apply {
        setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, 5, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
    }.also(textView::setText)`
```

Comment: мне нужно сделать это для android

Comment: SpannableString и есть андроидный класс, ты можешь использовать его

Comment: мне нужно сделать это В xml

Comment: ты не сможешь сделать это в xml по-нормальному, разве что разделить один текст на два TextView, но так никто не делает, потому что для этого есть Spannable, который я показал выше

Comment: огромное спасибо вам и удачи

Comment: @MartBalayan, вообще кое-какие html-тэги в строковых ресурсах поддерживаются - можете попробовать: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StylingWithHTML